# Question about compilation error related to a use in the keyword/reserved word "out"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, keyword

Hello 
I'm having an error with this code:
"**The out parameter 'o_BlockingSquaresArr' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method**"
Now this error paints each return statement of each method apart from the last one with red..
I don't understand what is the problem regarding my specific code
Please help me,
Thanks in Advance

```
internal bool isLegalMove(Square i_Move, out List<Square> o_BlockingSquaresArr) 
{
     bool result;

     if (m_GameBoard[i_Move.RowIndex, (int)i_Move.ColIndex].Coin != null)   
     {
          result = false;
          m_MessageBuffer = "You have enterd a square which is already
                             occupied, please try again...";       

          m_ErrorFlag=true;                                                                               
     }
     else
     {
          result = checkIfThereIsAtLeastOneSeqInOneDirection(i_Move,out o_BlockingSquaresArr);       
     }
     return result;

}

internal bool checkIfThereIsAtLeastOneSeqInOneDirection(Square i_Move, out List<Square> o_BlockingSquaresArr)
{
    const int k_EightDirections = 8;
    bool isSequenceFound, finalRes = false;

    for (int i = 1; i <= k_EightDirections; i++)    
    {
        isSequenceFound = checkOpponentSequenceInDirection(i_Move, (eDirections)i, out o_BlockingSquaresArr);     
        if (isSequenceFound)
        {
            finalRes = true;                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                         

    }
    return finalRes;
}

internal bool checkOpponentSequenceInDirection(Square i_Move, eDirections i_Direction, out List<Square> o_BlockingSquaresArr) 
{
     //I've shortened this code only relevant things  
     Square o_AdjacentSquare = new Square();
     adjacentCoin = doSwitchAndRetrieveAdjacentCoin(i_Move, i_Direction, out o_AdjacentSquare);

     // ...

     if (isThereAnOpponentSequence)
     {
          o_BlockingSquaresArr.Add(o_AdjacentSquare); 
     }
     return isThereAnOpponentSequence;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the compiler error says, an `out` parameter has to be definitely assigned before any non-exceptional return of a method. I can't see *any* assignment to `o_BlockingSquaresArr` anywhere. Why are you even declaring it as an `out` parameter to start with?

Comment: There *is* a place where it is assigned: it is passed as an out parameter to checkIfThereIsAtLeastOneSeqInOneDirection

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, but if you keep passing it as out parameters to another method, eventually there's got to be an explicit assignment. (Unless it recurses forever, of course :)

Comment: it ends in the internal bool checkOpponentSequenceInDirection  see the rest of the code on the bottom

Comment: @Mulder, yes, but checkOpponentSequenceInDirection isn't always called, and anyway you still don't initialize the parameter in checkOpponentSequenceInDirection, so it doesn't change anything

Comment: @Mulder: There's no assignment to `o_BlockingSquaresArr` in `checkOpponentSequenceInDirection`, is there? Where do you believe the variable is actually being assigned a value, exactly?

Comment: There is:  if (isThereAnOpponentSequence)
     {
          o_BlockingSquaresArr.Add(o_AdjacentSquare); 
     }

Comment: @Mulder: That's not an assignment. That's trying to call a method on a variable which isn't definitely assigned. An assignment would look like this: `o_BlockingSquaresArr = new List<Square>();`. But that's not what you've got. And even if you *did*, that's still only happening conditionally - the assignment has to occur however you return, so long as it doesn't end with an exception.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You are right it's the late hour... :)  Anyway I did an assignment in checkOpponentSequenceInDirection         o_BlockingSquaresArr = new List<Square>();     So I guess I will have to do so for all the rest of the levels up?

Comment: @Mulder: Well, you have to make sure that it becomes definitely assigned in each method where it's an out parameter, but that doesn't necessarily mean direct assignment - a variable used as an argument corresponding to an out parameter becomes definitely assigned too.

Comment: @ Jon: Sorry for all the mass but is there any other less complicated way to do what I want here, as you understand from the code- I know It's hard to understand this way but I cannot paste the whole code.Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Mulder: It's not really clear what you're trying to do, to be honest. I very *very* rarely use `out` parameters myself, partly because they *do* make things more complicated and harder to understand. Have you considered just returning the list instead of using an `out` parameter for it? The `bool` value is just going to be whether or not the list is empty, isn't it? In fact, you'll only ever end up with a single element in the list as far as I can see... so why not just return the element?

Comment: @jon: ok, it's a part of a reversi (aka: othello) game, I want to check if a move of a player is legal ,in other words: if placing a new coin on board is legal. If it is legal which means I will have a sequence of opponent coins near my new coin (which I will want to flip them to their other side) ending in an other coin of mine. So, inList<Square> o_BlockingSquaresArr are supposed to be all the edge squares which are holding the same color as I do. - I need their indexes because I want to flip the whole sequence of opponent coins between the edge coin and the new legal coin.

Comment: So as you can see the add to the list is being held only in the lowest method and then all I want is to pass this list up to the first level method for uses of other function. Thanks.

Comment: @jon:No, the bool of checkIfThereIsAtLeastOneSeqInOneDirection is for telling if the move is legal, for example the move is legal if and only if there is at least one Sequence of opponent coins in at least one direction, although I check all the 8 directions. Imagine a square on board in the middle of it is surrounded by 8 squares. So I want to take each edge coin of each direction if exist and to make a list of it - definitely not one element in a list...

Comment: @Mulder: Well that's not going to work with your current structure, because you only ever add a single element to the list in any one method call, and that's the same method call which creates the list. There's no way you'll end up with a list of more than one element. I think you've got some refactoring to do. I would also suggest that you come up with a new class to store the result - that way it can have both the `bool` value *and* the list. All of these could be instance methods on that class, too.

Answer (score 2):

An `out` parameter must be assigned a value before the method returns. In your `isLegalMove` method, `o_BlockingSquaresArr` is only assigned in the `else` block, so the compiler detects there are some cases where it is not initialized. You must make sure that *all* code paths in the method assign a value to `o_BlockingSquaresArr` before returning

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign something to the `out` parameter in every execution path. In your case, you forget that in one case. Simply assign a default value of the beginning of the method so you don't run into it.

I can't tell you where as you didn't include the method name it is happening in.

Answer (score 0):

In the IsLegalMove function, you need to assign a value to the o_BlockingSquaresArr variable

Comment: well I don't want to do so  as the assignment would happen couple of levels down in internal bool checkOpponentSequenceInDirection

Comment: @Mulder: Except that assignment *isn't* happening, is it?

Comment: @Jon Skeet:yes, because I think that logically if I'll do an assignment in other places it will ruin everything (logically)

Comment: @Mulder: But you haven't got an assignment **anywhere**. Where do you think you've got an assignment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign something to out parameters in every (normally terminating) codepath. And you don't do that.

For example in some functions you only assign to the parameter inside the for-loop. And if the loop has 0 iterations this will never happen.